# Average color (X11 colors)

Tags: graphics, x11, rgb, xlib

I want to fill the intersection of two(or more filled) rectangles with the average color. I have the colors of each rectangle stored as unsigned ints. How can I get the average color?

Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 2):

Technically, you might be running on a color-map device, which means you need to go through X11 color management for all of this. You need to query the `XColor` for your two input colors, compute the average, then look up the closest representable color:

```
// Query XColor for both input colors
XColor xcol1, xcol2, outcol;
xcol1.pixel = color1;
xcol2.pixel = color2;
XQueryColor(display, colormap, &xcol1);
XQueryColor(display, colormap, &xcol2);

// Average red/green/blue and look up nearest representable color
outcol.red = (xcol1.red + xcol2.red) / 2;
outcol.green = (xcol1.green + xcol2.green) / 2;
outcol.blue = (xcol1.blue + xcol2.blue) / 2;
XAllocColor(display, colormap, &outcol);

// outcol.pixel is now the color to use
```

On a paletted device, you also need to free the color afterwards etc. - it's a mess, basically.

But in all likelihood you're on a 32-bit truecolor device, which means the integer is just a bitfield of r, g, b and a (not necessarily in that order). You can compute their average like this:

```
UInt out_color = 0;
for (int i=0; i < 4; i++) {
  // Extract channel i from both input colors
  UInt in1 = (color1 >> (i*8)) & 0xff;
  UInt in2 = (color2 >> (i*8)) & 0xff;

  // Compute the average and or it into the output color
  out_color |= ((in1 + in2) / 2) << (i*8);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Color color1 = Color.FromArgb(UInt1);
Color color2 = Color.FromArgb(UInt2);
Color averageColor = Color.FromArgb(255,(color1.R + color2.R)/2,(color1.G + color2.G)/2,(color1.B + color2.B)/2);
```

This is assuming that you need a fully opaque average color.

Comment: -1. That's not Xlib code, or code for any X11 windowing toolkit for that matter.

Comment: You didn't mention X11 anywhere in your question.

Comment: The question is called "Average color (X11 colors)" and tagged as "x11" and "xlib" - that's quite explicit.